# Downloadable font: download failed

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am building this little MVC and everything works, but the fonts :/ I just can't get it working..

[this is my structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNoWT.png)

this is my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /vcMVC/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

# Otherwise rewrte to controller
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?controller=$1 [QSA,L]
```

thejs and css are loading well.. I also can download the fonts, when i call the link from the error-msg in the browser

Comment: downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "FontAwesome" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed source: http://www.meet-spot.de/vcMVC/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.4.0  font-awesome.min.css:4:14
Quellübergreifende (Cross-Origin) Anfrage blockiert: Die Gleiche-Quelle-Regel verbietet das Lesen der externen Ressource auf http://www.meet-spot.de/vcMVC/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.4.0. (Grund: CORS-Kopfzeile 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' fehlt).

Comment: Well ... try not keeping all of your PHP code in the `DOCUMENT_ROOT`. That would actually solve your problem. Also, don't use .htaccess file for routing.